# Strange behavior with fgets stdin and pipe character

Tags: c, stdin, fgets

I'm trying to read some text with fgets on stdin, but there's a strange behavior I don't understand.

Here is a simple code :

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    char chaine[30];
    int i;

    fgets(chaine, sizeof(chaine), stdin);
    printf("%s", chaine);

    for(i=0; i<strlen(chaine); i++) {
        printf("%d[%c][%u]\n", i, chaine[i], chaine[i]);
    }
}
```

And here is the output I have when I test it :

```
date | sasasa
date | sasasa
0[d][100]
1[a][97]
2[t][116]
3[e][101]
SPACE4[ ][32]
5[|][124]
6[?][4294967234]
7[?][4294967200]
8[s][115]
9[a][97]
10[s][115]
11[a][97]
12[s][115]
13[a][97]
14[
][10]
```

But it doesn't happen all the time .. The printf of the string is ok, but character by character, there's  this thing that looks like overflow.

And it happens only with pipe and space characters. The space character transforms into these two ?? characters.

I'm using the macosx terminal.

Does anyone has ever seen this behavior ?

Thanks for helping,

Comment: Most likely some unicode stuff. Are you copy-pasting from a word processor?

Comment: Seems to be working on my system? make sure there are no hidden characters in the input

Comment: When I'm testing it I type the characters myself. And sometimes, when typing the same thing, it happens or not.
And why would the printf be ok but not the character by character thing ?

Comment: What is the code page used? also, are you including the nul terminator in the string as well, sounds like you went over the boundary...

Comment: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00a0/index.htm - you're somehow typing that char (0xC2A0, print hex values rather than %u to see).

Comment: `printf("%d[%c][%u]\n", i, chaine[i], chaine[i]);` -->> `printf("%d[%c][%x]\n", i, (int) chaine[i], (unsigned) chaine[i]);`

Comment: @t0mm13b He stops at `strlen(chaine)`, that checks for the null terminator.

Comment: @Barmar sure, look at offset 14 in there, notice how its 10... which is what am wondering about. oh wait, that's a return character... my bad..

Comment: Ok I think I found out. Here is what I get when I type "locale" in my terminal (mac osx btw) :
LANG=  
Like nothing is defined ..

Comment: @Mat How is a value > 255 getting into a `char` array? Isn't `char` supposed to be 1 byte?

Comment: I tried to set the LANG envvar to en_US.UTF-8, but the same thing still happens

Comment: a tip, initialise the array with a character like, 'X', from beginning to end, then watch the output, that will give the clue, whether its the buffer or something else, canonical input, raw input... ?

Comment: @Barmar I think it's a negative value like -96 that is printed as an unsigned int, that's why. I shouldn't have used %u

Comment: @Alakartes I don't think `LANG` has anything to do with it, I suspect a terminal emulator issue. When you type space you're getting a non-breaking space instead.

Comment: @Alakartes the locale would need to be re-generated, try log out and log back in again,

Comment: But why the space before the pipe is okay and the other one ins't ? That's what I don't understand : different behavior, but same key hit.

Comment: which terminal are you using? @Barmar is right about the terminal emulator. OP, you should edit the question to state that the environment is Mac OSX which is buried in the comments.

Comment: I'm using the macosx terminal. I'll try on debian when I have an occasion to do so

Comment: is your keyboard recognized on the mac, that is, the filter bar | ? ITs not triggering a locale switch or any weird macro associated with it?

Comment: Okay, I found out .. Turns out I'm using a Windows keyboard map, because I'm used to it. I returned to the Macosx layout and the problem is gone ..

Comment: That simple? /facepalms

Comment: `SPACE` was not in the output right?

Comment: @Barmar the large numbers are Undefined Behaviour caused by using the wrong format specifier  (`%u` must have `unsigned int` argument)